# ConvertTo-Json throws error when using a string terminating in backslash

Tags: powershell

The following bit of code generates an error

```
W:\surge\ogre> @{SolutionDir='W:\Surge\ogre\'} | ConvertTo-Json
ConvertTo-Json : The converted JSON string is in bad format.
At line:1 char:35
+ @{SolutionDir='W:\Surge\ogre\'} | ConvertTo-Json
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collections.Hashtable:PSObject) [ConvertTo-Json], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JsonStringInBadFormat,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToJsonCommand
```

Why? How could I fix this? This is in a prebuild event so I'm trying to keep it single-line and as compact as possible.

Comment: Frankly: it looks like a bug in handling trailing `\`. It works fine if you ConvertFrom-Json proper data, but not other way around.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using the `-Compress` switch should solve your problem. I believe this is a bug in PowerShell. Others have had similar problem with ex. values [containing double quotes](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/735978/convertto-json-in-psv3-beta-does-not-support-values-containing-double-quotes)

Comment: Yes that did it, thank you and thanks for the link to the bug tracker so I can report the issue

Comment: Great. Create a new connect bug report as your problem isn't 100% equal. It shows however, that the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet needs a bit of work from MS's part. The error still occurs in PowerShell 5.0 preview. Please add the link to your bug report in a comment so viewers can upvote it.

Comment: [Created here](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/869768/powershell-convertto-json-error-when-has-string-with-trailing-backslash)

Comment: Hey George, it looks like your bug report moved [here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11088063-powershell-convertto-json-error-when-has-string-wi).

Comment: In my particular case, the issue was that the string value of a property _ended_ with a "\", e.g. `"\\server-name\path\to\files\"`. With the trailing slash on the string value, the serializer used by `ConvertTo-JSON` resulted in this error and choked. Trimming the "\" off the end of the property value allowed `ConvertTo-JSON` to work properly. Yes, this is still technically a bug--but I'm using `Join-Path` to create paths, so this is an acceptable workaround for me without having to use `-Compress`.