# How to access variables relating to a TFS commit in build definition

Tags: tfs

I'm using the "Post to Slack" task as one of my build steps in TFS 2018 and I'm wondering how to access variables relating to that commit. I would like to include them as part of the Message field (something like "Commit: $(CommitMessage) link to changeset $(ChangesetLink)" but those variables don't exist). Here is where I need to reference the variables in TFS:

[image]

This document: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch) describes how to access build variables but it doesn't mention anything relating to the commit. I would like to access the commit message, associated commit changesets and the link to the changeset(s) associated with the commit. Does anyone know how to do this or know where I can find documentation for it? Thank you

Comment: TFS / VSTS REST APIs allows to do lot more than basics. have you done some research on REST APIs?.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20commits?view=vsts-rest-5.0

Comment: @cruiser that looks great, do you know how to access these as variables in the build definition? Like for instance comment, would it be $(GitCommit.comment)?

Comment: I am do not know if there are predefined variables for your needs. 
But these REST API may get you there. If you are running on a Windows based agent, then you can write powershell scripts ( if not sh based) to invoke REST API, parse the results, then use ##vso[task.setvariable variable=name;]value to set the value to the list of variables. 

Reference Link from Stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881017/tfs-ci-build-update-custom-define-variable-after-build-is-succeed

Comment: There is a Slack service hook built in. What about that doesn't meet your needs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/slack?view=vsts

Comment: I'm not sure how to access/call the REST API from the build definition, if possible I'd like to do it from the UI for ease of use. I edited my post to include a picture that will clarify where I need to access these variable names.

Comment: @DanielMann I'm not sure how that would help me with the "Post to Slack" task, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ryan It wouldn't, it would completely remove the need for it. The Slack service hook allows messages to be posted to a Slack channel when certain events (such as, say, builds starting or completing) occur.

Answer (score 1):

Cruiser is right, no such [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#predefined-variables) in TFS, you can retrieve the needed information by [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20commits?view=vsts-rest-5.0#all_commits), then set corresponding variables using the [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).

1. Create a PowerShell script to set the avariables (Reference below
   sample, you can also [Use the OAuth token to access the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/scripts/powershell?view=vsts#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api)), then commit and push the script into TFS.
2. Add a `PowerShell` task **before** the "`Post to Slack`" task in your
   definition to run the PS script
3. Use the variables `$(commitID)`, `$(CommitMessage)` and
   `$(commitUrl)` in "`Post to Slack`" task

**Note**: *For Git it's commit, For TFVC it's [changeset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/changesets/get?view=vsts-rest-5.0)*

You can use below script to set the variables:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection", 
   [string]$repoid = "389e8215-1fb2-4fdc-bd04-ebc8a8a4410e",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$searchCriteria = "$" + "top=1"

$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/_apis/git/repositories/$repoid/commits?$searchCriteria"          
$response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

#Retrieve values 
$commitID = $response.value.commitID
$CommitMessage = $response.value.comment
$commitUrl = $response.value.remoteUrl

#Set variables
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=commitID]$commitID"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CommitMessage]$CommitMessage"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=commitUrl]$commitUrl"
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You can use this REST API to get the repository ID:

`GET http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{ProjectName}/_apis/git/repositories`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, do you know how I can get my repo id?

Comment: @Ryan You can use REST API `GET http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{ProjectName}/_apis/git/repositories` to get the repository ID.

Comment: @Ryan Have you resolved the issue by the answer above? any update?